# Impossible to connect to server with ssh without password

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, sshd

I tried different solutions but none of them work.

I generated a key with ssh-keygen on a machine. I add this key on a linux server in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and it works perfectly.

On a second linux server, I did the same. But it doesn't work. I tried different things :

- Put my key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys2`
- Edited `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (by commenting and uncommenting lines)
- Gave the right rights (700 to `.ssh` directory and 600 to authorized_keys files)

Nothing seems to work... Still asking me a password.

What could be the problem ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :

`sshd_config

```
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
#PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers user

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

My ssh -vv result

`OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-128-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-128-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup umac-128-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-128-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1580/3072
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ED25519 67:fd:fd:6e:a5:c1:32:96:9d:33:32:1a:cf:83:94:ea
debug1: Host '[IP]:22' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1546/3072
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f84b8ce74a0),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method`
user@IP's password:

`/var/log/auth.log` (on the distant server)

`Jul 12 12:24:43 ns3111463 sshd[12971]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
Jul 12 12:24:44 ns3111463 sshd[12971]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:24:46 ns3111463 sshd[12973]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:24:48 ns3111463 sshd[11787]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul 12 12:24:48 ns3111463 sshd[12977]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 12 12:24:48 ns3111463 sshd[12977]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 12 12:24:50 ns3111463 sshd[12978]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:24:51 ns3111463 sshd[12980]: User root from IP not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Jul 12 12:24:51 ns3111463 sshd[12980]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
Jul 12 12:24:51 ns3111463 sshd[12980]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:25:49 ns3111463 sshd[12977]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul 12 12:25:49 ns3111463 sshd[13029]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 12 12:25:49 ns3111463 sshd[13029]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 12 12:25:50 ns3111463 sshd[13030]: User root from IP not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Jul 12 12:25:50 ns3111463 sshd[13030]: input_userauth_request: invalid user root [preauth]
Jul 12 12:25:51 ns3111463 sshd[13030]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:25:53 ns3111463 sshd[13032]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:37:41 ns3111463 sshd[13552]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]
Jul 12 12:38:09 ns3111463 sshd[13598]: Connection closed by IP [preauth]`

Comment: Can you paste sshd_config in your question ?

Comment: I did it. By the way, I already uncommented `AuthorizedKeysFile` line, changed the path, etc...

Comment: You have "PermitRootLogin No" in your sshd_config. This might prevent you from logging in as root, as you seem to be trying. (Note that it's almost always a bad idea to turn this on, it's better to use normal users.)

Comment: I commented the line `PermitRootLogin no` and I uncommented the line `PermitRootLogin without-password`, I restart ssh service with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` but still asking me the password. Do I have to reload something else ? By the way, I accept to connect with my other user called "user" but same error.

Comment: Which distro are you using. In newest CentOS and Debian you should restart sshd using systemctl

Comment: I'm under Debian 8

Comment: `AllowUsers user`  This will allow only `user` to log in.

Comment: @val0x00ff I added ",root" this line to allowed root as well (to try).

Answer (score 1):

So you have `PermitRootLogin no` and authorized_keys file in root home directory. Try to use `PermitRootLogin without-password` instead. Then restart SSH server:

```
systemctl restart sshd.service
```

For the notice: it's better to forbid root login over SSH even with keys. Create custom user instead, and login to SSH using this user. You can then `su` to switch to root.

**EDIT:**

If you want to login as not root, you have to put your public key in the authorized_keys file of your user:

```
/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**EDIT2:**

To disable authenticating with passwords for all users set `PasswordAuthentication no` and restart SSH server.

Comment: Okay, I have a custom user called "user". I'm using now `PermitRootLogin without-password` instead of `PermitRootLogin no`. I restarted the service but when I'm trying `user@myIPadress` it still asks me my password.

Comment: I edited answer for this. Check it out

Comment: I created a .ssh inside my "user" home (`/home/user/.ssh`) directory with permission 700 and I put the `authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2` inside it with permission 600. Still not working...

Comment: Are use using ssh command? You have to specify your key file: `ssh user@ip -i $path_to_key`. If you want to disable passwords for all users you have to set `PasswordAuthentication no`

Comment: I'm simply using `ssh user@IP`. Worked for some linux servers but not this one.

Comment: I want to keep the authentication with password for root !

Comment: Because any key in your /root/.ssh doesn't not match key you specified in authorized_keys on your server. If key doesn't match server prompts for password, because your current config allows that

Comment: Do you even know what you want exactly? `PasswordAuthentication no` disables password authentication over SSH for all users allowing only login users with authorized_keys. This DO NOT disable passwords in your system. It's more secure.

Comment: I just generated new key. On my source server, I have the key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and I pasted it in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys2`, `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to be sure. I restarted the service ssh (even if it's not necessary) and I still have the prompt...

Comment: I want to disable the password for ssh only for my user "user".

Comment: Edit question also with output of `grep ssh /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: I did it @mrc02_kr

Comment: Log says that you are trying to login as root but root is not allowed. Remove your user's key from /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and leave it only in your user's directory

Comment: I just executed `rm /root/.ssh/authorized_keys*`, so the directory is now empty (except the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub). Do I have to launch something else after that ?

Comment: Try to connect to server explicitly using ssh_key: ssh $server_ip -i $key_path

Comment: Still not working. What I will do now : generate new public key for "root" in the source server , add it in /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys and try to connect. Because I have too many keys now and it starts to be difficult to understand.

Comment: You can try that if it's too much keys already.  Also check [Debian Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.remote-login.html#sect.ssh) point 9.2.1.1. to make sure you doing it right

Comment: I put mistakes in the `sshd_config` file to see if an error would have been thrown but nothing appeared when I launched `systemctl restart sshd.service`. Is there a way to see if file is good ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have to be careful since ssh is really picky about the rights when it comes to public key authentication.

You're at least right on the `.ssh` which should be limited, however that is not all. The `/root` must also be limited and owned by the user respectivly.

So try adjusting the "home" of the user aswell with `755` so the group cannot write into the home + the right owner of the home is also assigned.

Also why are you using "authorized_keys2" instead of "authorized_keys", I don't think that will work?

Comment: I tried to create the .ssh directory inside my user home too. Look under the previous answer.

Comment: show us your ssh connection with `-vv`

Comment: I edited my question. Take a look

Comment: Comment out the "AllowUsers user" or add root to them. + Like the others said uncommenting `PermitRootLogin without-password` and commenting the `PermitRootLogin no`

Comment: I'm using `authorized_keys`, just tried with `authorized_keys2` because the file was in the `.ssh` directory.